# Code highlighting of string continues after \"

Tags: bug, code-formatting, android-app, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-app

The newly released Stack Overflow App contains a bug resulting in a wrong coloring after the ending of a string.

I looked up my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997765/1351167) on Stack Overflow, inside the Stack Exchange App, the mobile and desktop website, the first code block (Encoding) is displayed correctly.

```c#
private void Encode()
{
    Job j = new Job();
    MediaItem m = new MediaItem(txtBxVideoFilePath.Text);
    Source s = m.Sources[0];
    s.Clips[0].StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    s.Clips[0].EndTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    j.OutputDirectory= @"C:\Users\MyOutputDir\";
    j.MediaItems.Add(m);
    j.Encode();
    txtBxOutputDir.Text = j.ActualOutputDirectory; //Path to your videofile
}
```

The Code Highlighter of the Stack Overflow app is not recognizing the ending of the string, most likely due to the backslash before the quotes:

*@"C:\Users\MyOutputDir **\";***

These two screenshots hopefully illustrate the problem.

[image: Stack Exchange Code Highlighting]
[image: Stack Overflow Code Highlighting]

Edit#1:

This bug doesn't seem to only affect the app but more the general highlighting on some circumstances.

[image: StackExchange Bug Overview]

Comment: Okay, that's a trip. On the desktop, it works on main, but not on Meta...

Comment: Whoa this is an awesome fine, looking into it, thanks!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi And it seems to not only affect the app (see the graphic after the edit)

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih thanks for that matrix! I _think_ it's either to do with the version of Prettify.js being used on the different sites and apps, or with the prettify language setting. Will let you know once I figure it out!